# Erro de compilação do .jar via linha de comando no Spring Boot/Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, maven

Tenho uma aplicação de estudos de RestApi e estou usando o Spring para tal fim. Na hora de compilar o jar via linha de comando, apresenta este erro abaixo. Já mudei versão do driver e não resolveu.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-08-21 10:48:38.461 ERROR 11284 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at api.rest.SpringrestapiApplication.main(SpringrestapiApplication.java:24) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [springrestapi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [springrestapi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [springrestapi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [springrestapi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:224) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:44) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:88) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e356cb4.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e356cb4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ba93bf1e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e356cb4.dataSource(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
```

meu pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>2.0.3.RELEASE</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

meu application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

#criar automaticamente as tabelas dos modelos
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

server.servlet.context-path=/springrestapi
```

já procurei em tudo quanto é lugar e nada de resolver. Alguém dá uma luz?

Answer (score 0):

Boa Noite, tudo bem?

Já tentou utilizar essa versão?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901.jdbc3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta adicionar essas linhas no seu application.properties.

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001883/spring-boot-to-postgres-database-driver-issue